# UIView Animationn in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, uianimation

Can someone tell me what mistake I have done in following code?

```
 func animateView(view: UIView){
       view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.view.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image]

I want animation like this. I read it on some blog but I didn't get how use it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear what you expect. Setting a view's `transform` to `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)` has no effect, because that is its scale by default. And then animating it to `.identity` has no effect, because that is its transform by default. So I would not expect your code to have any visible effect.

Comment: Why "unclear what you expect"? The OP showed a gif of the animation they expect to see. The thing that's unclear is whether this is a simple typo or a genuine misunderstanding of what `CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX:y:)` does. @matt

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, I see what you mean. I think I was responding more to the fact that the OP provided code but no statement of how the result differs from the desired effect. Also, for all I know, the OP also expects to see the little circle sliding along the time-vs-scale curve, and _that_ is certainly not going to happen just by changing the transform.

Comment: @matt you r right it's not giving any effect

Comment: @matt my view has 400 height and width is equal to viewcontroler any solution?

Comment: @matt Thank you so much it start working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake lies in the first line, where you set the `transform` to a scale of `(1, 1)`:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
```

`CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)` means a scale with *scale factor* of 1, i.e. normal scale. This is equivalent to `.identity`, so you're askibf it to animate a transformation *from* the identity transform *to* the identity transform.

I'm guessing you probably thought `(1, 1)` meant 1 pixel by 1 pixel?

You should instead set the scale to `(0, 0)` initially:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
```

Your second mistake is that you are animating `self.view`, not the parameter `view`. This is likely a typo.

so your whole method looks like:

```
func animateView(view: UIView){
   view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        view.transform = .identity
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right but ```view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0) ``` disappear my view.

Comment: @MuhammadHasanIrshad But after the view disappears, the animation starts, right?

Comment: @MuhammadHasanIrshad Found a typo. See the edit. You need to change `self.view` to just `view` in the closure.